# UTF-8 Dingbats In ColdFusion

Tags: html, utf-8, coldfusion

I'm trying to display some hex and decimal encoded special characters ([UTF-8 Dingbats](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp)) in a coldfusion (v11) page.

`<cfloop>
   <td id="..." align="center">&#9986;</td>
   <td id="..." align="center">&#x2702;</td>
</cfloop>`

Based on the compiler error it most certainly seems like an issue with the pound (#) character, which of course is a special character in coldfusion.

So, is what I'm trying to do even possible, maybe by escaping #?

Comment: Escape the pound character like so &##x2702;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ColdFusion the `#` is used to output variables within an `<cfoutput>` block. For example.

```
<cfoutput>The time is #now()#</cfoutput>
```

If you need to preserve the `#`, then you need to escape it, which you can do with a double `#`. For example:

```
<cfoutput>My dingbats: &##9986; &##x2702;</cfoutput>
```

If you're not inside a `cfoutput` block then you don't need to escape it. For example:

```
<cfoutput>My dingbat: &##9986;</cfoutput><br>
My dingbat: &#x2702;
```

Comment: Ok. My snippet above is actually within a <cfloop>, which I failed to omit and could've definitely caused confusion. Thanks for clarifying (you can still be a musician, I program synthesizers from sequencers, can't play anything but am learning keyboard/piano).

Comment: Low hanging fruit - easy score for you John (ha).

Comment: Actually this explanation isn't fully correct. The hash/pound/# is a literal used to enclose a term that is supposed to be evaluated by ColdFusion at runtime, e.g. `<cfset x = "#">` has nothing to do with `<cfoutput>`, yet it will cause the template parser to fail. ##smartass

Comment: @Alex ha - like the escaped `##` in your comment! @Mark consider me busted :)